# Symfony3.4: The option "choices" with value [...] is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type [...]

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, when I corresponded to "" deleted in symfony3 or later, the following error occurred.
I don't think I'm using the "" anymore, but it seems to be recognized by symfony.
`composer dump-autoload` and `php bin/console cache:clear` have been executed.
Is there anything wrong with it?

https://.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/UPGRADE-2.7.md

Error

```
The option "choices" with value Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\
 is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type 
"Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\".
```

StaffChoiceList.php->StaffChoiceLoader.php

```php
// use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\;
// use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
use AppBundle\Model\Service\StaffService;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface;

// class StaffChoiceList extends 
class StaffChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    private $loginStaff;

    private $currentStaff;
    /**
     * @var StaffService
     */
    private $staffService;

    public function __construct(StaffService $staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }

    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }
    // Add"$value = null"
    public function ($value = null)
    {
        // Get the same shop staff as the login staff
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        // If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
        return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
    }
    //Add
    public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value = null)
    {
        // TODO: Implement loadChoicesForValues() method.
    }
    //Add
    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value = null)
    {
        // TODO: Implement loadValuesForChoices() method.
    }
}
```

ArticleType.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory;
use AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\StaffChoiceLoader;

abstract class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
       // $authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceList($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
        //Add
        $factory = new DefaultChoiceListFactory();
        $authorChoiceList = $factory->createListFromLoader(new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']));

        $builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AppBundle:Staff",
            "choices" => $authorChoiceList,
            "placeholder" => "Please select",
        ));
```

**Tried Code**
1.　`choices` -> `choice_loader`
The following error

```
The option "choice_loader" with value Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ is expected to be of type "null" or "Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface", but is of type "Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\".
```

2. Change `$authorChoiceList`

```
        // $factory = new DefaultChoiceListFactory();
        // $authorChoiceList = $factory->createListFromLoader(new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']));
        $authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
```

The following error

```
Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

AbstractController->createForm('AppBundle\\Form\\Type\\Article\\BrandEventType', object(BrandEvent), array('method' => 'POST', 'action' => '/app_dev.php/admin/hq/brandevent/', 'login_staff' => object(Staff)))
in src/AppBundle/Controller/BaseArticleController.php (line 186)

        ));
        } else if ($articleType == 'brandevent'){
           $form = $this->createForm(BrandEventType::class, $article, array(
            "method" => "POST",
            "action" => $this->generateUrl($this->createRoute,
 array("articleType" => $articleType)),
            //Error Code
            "login_staff" => $this->getStaff(),
        ));
        }
```

Comment: `$factory->createListFromLoader()` returns a `LazyChoiceList` (see https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/3.4/ChoiceList/Factory/DefaultChoiceListFactory.php)

Comment: @jona303 Thanks for your comment.
The method was different in the first place. Do you know an alternative method?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-loader

Comment: @jona303 I tried choice_loader but it didn't work. I added it to the question. Am I doing something wrong?